# Ionic - How to import ViewController properly? - Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for ViewController

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a [Popover](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/) and I would like my app to behave differently depending on the selected item. 
To achieve that I have followed that [Ionic Doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/).

```
 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for ViewController!
```

So if I add ViewController to `app.module.ts` I receive the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ViewController: (?, ?, ?)
```

**Question**: How to import ViewController properly?

popover component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'popover',
  templateUrl: 'popover.html'
})
export class PopoverComponent {

  popoverItemList = [{name: 'Event erstellen'}, {name: 'Event Übersicht'}];

  selectedTitle: string;

  constructor(private viewCtrl: ViewController) {
    this.selectedTitle = "";
  }

  setSelectedTitle(selectedItem) {
   this.selectedTitle = selectedItem;
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.selectedTitle);
  }

}
```

I call the popover like that:

```
presentPopover(ev) {
   let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopoverComponent, {
   });
   popover.present({
     ev: ev
   });

   popover.onDidDismiss((popoverData) => {
      if(popoverData === 'Event erstellen') {
        this.navCtrl.push(CreateEventPage, {

        });
      } else if(popoverData === 'Event Übersicht') {
        this.navCtrl.push(EventlistPage, {

        });
      }
    })
```

Comment: You need to simulate it on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: are you using lazy loading? which module is `PopoverComponent` declared?

Comment: Did you import `IonicModule` in your `app.module` ?

Answer (score 0):

import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

Not declare in Construct, but in @ViewChild(ViewController) view: ViewController;

Answer (score 0):

```
import { ModalController } from   '@ionic/angular';

constructor(private viewCtrl : ModalController) { }
this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
```

Answer (score -4):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'popover',
  templateUrl: 'popover.html',
  providers : [ViewController] //add this line
})
export class PopoverComponent {

  popoverItemList = [{name: 'Event erstellen'}, {name: 'Event Übersicht'}];

  selectedTitle: string;

  constructor(private viewCtrl: ViewController) {
    this.selectedTitle = "";
  }

  setSelectedTitle(selectedItem) {
   this.selectedTitle = selectedItem;
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.selectedTitle);
  }

}
```

Comment: No way!! Put it in app.module.ts. Not a provider per component

Comment: even if you do this bad workaround..how does it avoid `Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ViewController: (?, ?, ?)`?